# Repetitive word completion list in Sublime Text 3

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

I customized a language package (NCL), where I defined the keywords in `NCL.tmLanguage.JSON` and some completion entries in `NCL.sublime-completions`.

Some keywords are now listed twice when editing a NCL file, because it presents in both `NCL.tmLanguage.JSON` and `NCL.sublime-completions`.

[image]

Some keywords only in `NCL.tmLanguage.JSON` are not listed.

**Question:** How do I get a clean and correct completion list?

Comment: The completion list (as far as I know) is not populated by the tmLanguage file. Is it possible you have multiple `*.sublime-completion` files that contain the same snippet?

Comment: @skuroda Thanks for reminding me. I have kept two versions of NCL package, one is my development version, the other is installed from Package Control for testing.